# Symbian S60 - Multiple connections with a single connection dialog

Tags: singleton, symbian, s60

My application needs up to 3 simultaneous download connections. I am currently using a (slightly altered) CWebClient class provided in the Carbide UI framework, however using multiple instances of this for each connection prompts me multiple types to "select access point"

An `RSocketServ` and an `RConnection` object exist in the class, these appear to be the things that open the access point. Would it be a good enough solution to make these static objects (singleton) so the access point is only called once?

Any one have any experience/thoughts?

Thanks!

Just in case you wonder, I am using S60 3rd ed. FP2 v1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RConnection should be the class that triggers the access point selection dialog.

If you write your own code, get one instance of RSocketServ and 3 instances of RSocket. That should be enough. The access point selection dialog will only occur when the connection is established, which will happen only once until you hit a non-coverage area or your downloads time out.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to suppress "Select Access Point" dialog. You can do it by using CIntConnectionInitiator to establish a connection. Although this class isn't documented there is a bunch of examples on [forum.nokia.com](http://forum.nokia.com).

Answer (score 0):

Roll your own accesspoint (AP) selector and store the AP ID .
Then use TCommDbConnPref to set AP ID and suppress the dialog.